# Balanced AC Bridge Solution

Tags: circuit-analysis

A balanced AC bridge has the following constants:

- Branch AB, R = 2000(ohm) in parallel with C = 0,047uf (microfarad);
- Branch BC, R = 1000(ohm) in serie with C = 0.47uf(microfarad);
- Branch CD is unknown;
- Branch DA, C = 0.5(ohm*farad).
- The oscillator frequency is 1000 Hz;

I need to find the constants of branch CD.

This is what I got so far, in the image is the circuit and the solution I'm giving to it, I suppose that to find z4(CD branch) I have to divide it with z1(AB branch) but my question is, what I have to do with the imaginary (i), how the result will involve that imaginary (i) or what is the purpose of it. How will be the solution?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Learn about image cropping, resolution and JPEG artifacts

Comment: ...and learn about complex numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm new to Stackexchange and it's great that people help you, I just crop the image, I can't get a better resolution...

Comment: There are **two simultaneous balance conditions** that must be satisfied in a 4 arm ac bridge  - magnitude **and** phase.  I think you'll also find that frequency is very relevant when calculating impedances and phase angles.  Here's a little bit of reading for you http://www.nct-tech.edu.lk/Download/Technology%20Zone/AC%20Bridges.pdf

Comment: I see where the assertion there are "two simultaneous balance conditions" comes from. Your statement is true if Z1…Z4 are assumed to be the magnitudes only of the complex impedances. If you assume that Z1…Z4 are, in fact, complex numbers, then they inherently contain the phase information, and there is only one balance condition Z1*Z4 = Z2*Z3, because the complex arithmetic takes care of both mangitude and phase simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the bridge is balanced when Z1/Z3 = Z2/Z4. The frequency and the impedance AC are irrelevant at balance.

Rearranging the expression gives Z4 = Z2*Z3/Z1. I would recommend you only substitute component values after you have algebraically arrived at the final expression for Z4. In general when you multiply the complex quantities Zn = Rn||Cn together, you will find there are terms like (Rn + iwCn) in the denominator. Multiply both numerator and denominator by (Rn - iwCn), recognizing that i*i = -1, which will clear out any imaginary quantities in the denominator, leaving only an expression like (Pr - iPc) in the numerator (Pr and Pc will be complicated expressions). The Pc will correspond to C4, the Pr to R4.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just found a similar problem(attached a new image on the post), but according to your answer it's different, can you explain me how they got that solution at the end and how they managed the imaginary quantities? Thanks

Comment: This is what you mean?
                                    Z4 = Z2*Z3/Z1;
   Z4= Z2*Z3/(R + jwC);
   Z4= (R - jwC)*Z2*Z3/(R + jwC)*(R - jwC);
   Z4= (R4-C4);

Comment: Almost. Remember the impedance of a capacitor is Zc = 1/jwC, so that Zrc = R||C = R/(1+jwRC)

Comment: Like this? Z4 = Z2*Z3/Z1; Z4= Z2*Z3/(R/(1+jwRC));  Z4= (R - jwC)*Z2*Z3/(R/(1+jwRC)*(R - jwC), my answer have to have that i, imaginary?

Comment: Closer. In this case, you're missing a bracket, and allowing for that you really need to write Z4= (1+jwRC)*Z2*Z3/ (R/(1+jwRC))*(1+jwRC) =(1+jwRC)*Z2*Z3/R

Comment: but (1-jwRC) would be negative, right? Z4= (1-jwRC)*Z2*Z3/ (R/(1+jwRC))*(1-jwRC) =(1+jwRC)*Z2*Z3/R

Comment: (1-jwRC) would be the complex conjugate of (1+jwRC), but if you examine my previous answer you'll see that the denominator of the expression for Z4 is actually R/(1+jwRC) and multiplying the denominator (and the numerator of the Z4 expression) by (1+jwRC) results in R/(1+jwRC) * (1+jwRC) = R

Comment: Ok so I got Z4=(1+jwRC)*Z2*Z3/R, from there how do I get (Pr-iPc)?

Comment: You need to substitute for Z2 and Z3 as well...

Comment: How do I get rid of the imaginary quantities in the numerator?

Comment: You collect them all together. That collection of imaginary quantities is Pc.

Comment: The questions you are asking are about basic complex number operations. You really need to learn about complex numbers.